# Can I divide the pages into categories?

Tags: posts, categories, pages

I wanto know if I can divide the pages into categories? Going into the Wp administration panel I can see that I can create some categories for the posts but it seems to me that I can't do it for the pages. Why? What am I missing?

Tnx

Comment: You're not missing anything, pages don't have categories.

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin which does this perfectly:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/post-tags-and-categories-for-pages/